# Name folder and file from cell, and save the file in the folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Here is, what I want the macro to do:

1. Create new folder defined by a cell in Excel.
2. Open xxx numbers of word-documents to update chain references.
3. Save Word-documents with different filenames defined by cells in Excel.
4. Save Word-documents (in the new folder) with different filenames defined by cells in Excel.
5. Close Word-documents.

Almost all works fine, but so far I can only save files into an existing folder (New customer).

Code looks like this:

````
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\New customer"
'Check if the folder exists
If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

 'Folder does not exist, so create it
 MkDir folderPath
 
  Else
     MsgBox "Mappe med samme navn eksisterer allerede"
     
End If
 
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
 wordapp.Documents.Open "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\test.docx"
 wordapp.Visible = True
 'Auto save

 wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\New customer\" & Sheets("Testark").Range("A8")
 wordapp.Documents.Close
 

 wordapp.Documents.Open "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\test2.docx"
 wordapp.Visible = True
 'Auto save
 wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\New customer\" & Sheets("Testark").Range("B8")
 wordapp.Documents.Close
    
    
End Sub```
````

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Also: Does `C:\Users\Path\ ` exists? That looks as if you have a user named `Path`

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
folderPath = "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\New customer"
```

Tells your code where to save it. You need to change the definition of folderpath to something other than "New customer" if you want to save elsewhere.

i.e. something like...

```
Dim strFolder as String
Let strFolder = Cell1.value
folderPath = "C:\Users\klebg\OneDrive\Zitekick\Kunder\Byg & Brand\TEST\" & strFolder
```

Comment: Hi Charles. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I'm aware of, whar you´re suggesting, but what I want is to save the document in a new folder, with a foldername defined by a cell text (see 1. in my description). Therefore I can't just rename "New customer".

Comment: See my edited answer.